# Internal Storage doesn't get mounted

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, internal-sd

I'm using PA3+ JB 4.1.2 on my HTC Vivid. Everything was working fine until Gmail app gets an update. After update, phone went into a bootloop. To recover, I went into TWRP and restored factory default, cleared cache and dalvik cache et cetra. Bootloop issue resolved but now when I'm trying to open Gallery/Camera app, it's giving me `No external Storage Available` error. In setting, when I try to mount internal SD card; nothing happens. I tried to mount card from TWRP but still, nothing is happening.

Should I flash ROM completely? Or is there any workaround to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

I'm getting `Unable to mount /emmc (Invalid Argument)` error quite often in TWRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be your ROM. You could start by clearing the cache and dalvik. If it were me, I'd back up my sms and mms and do a full flash. I doubt a factory reset alone will help. I had an issue with permissions when my phone was connected to USB with certain ROMS, sometimes accessing with my PC, sometimes through recovery. I have to believe it's ROM related since the current version of PAC-man I'm using has been much more cooperative. I doubt it's driver related, but that'd be the safest starting point if you have sensitive data on your phone.